# Counting repeat registers by column value with a simple query

Tags: mysql, sql

Given that I have the following table:

```
Id, Date, Data Identifier, Info
1, 2013-01-01, 'XSWQ', '#1'
2, 2013-01-02, 'ADWS', '#1'
3, 2013-01-02, 'ADWS', '#2'
4, 2013-01-02, 'QKVJ', '#1'
5, 2013-01-03, 'XSWQ', '#1'
6, 2013-01-03, 'ADWS', '#1'
7, 2013-01-04, 'QKVJ', '#1'
8, 2013-01-04, 'VSAQ', '#1'
9, 2013-01-04, 'VSAQ', '#2'
```

How can I counting the repeat registers (same Data Identifier in different Dates) with a unique and simple SQL (no subqueries) for a limited period but comparing records of all time?

For example, I want to count duplicate records that appear between 2013-01-02 and 2013-01-04 considering the entire table. The 'VSAQ' shouldn`t be considered repeated, but 'XSWQ' should be considered a duplicate record (the first appearance of it is outside the period stated).

Then the result is 3 (XSWQ, ADWS, QKVJ)

Is it possible with a unique and simple query?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT tbl.Identifier
FROM tbl
LEFT JOIN tbl AS everything
ON tbl.Identifier = everything.Identifier
  AND tbl.Id <> everything.Identifier
WHERE tbl.Date BETWEEN '2013-01-02' AND '2013-01-04'
  AND everything.id IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY tbl.Identifier
```

but why the anti-subquery?  The subquery may be quicker
See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/19fb3/5

Comment: No problems, just to understand whether we can do in a single query. This query finds records that appear more than once in one day? In my case, I can not consider these lines as repeated.